# Run time error '424' when using the same worksheet title

Tags: vba, excel

I have an error that shows Run-time error '424': Object required. I have provided the image and hope it will be clearer.

I have name sheet as test and tried running but it showed the error. But when i change the sheet to Sheet1, it some how works.

[image]

Please let me know if there is something wrong with my code.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Sheets("test")

For example

```
Set vCell = Sheets("test").cells(otherrow,1)
```